# UK Student Visa Delay

Tags: visas, uk, application-status, student-visas

I applied for new student visa on 15th of July and today, I haven't got any update. I called the UKVI this morning and the lady said nothing is showing on her system about my application. I emailed my school last week and this response was given.
UKVI have confirmed that you should receive the result of your application shortly. Can someone help?

Comment: What help exactly are you looking for? You’ve got a reply from UKVI/your school, I don’t mean to sound unsympathetic but no-one on TSE can provide any insight into what’s taking so long.

Comment: Asking if this has happened to any one here? Perhaps i am a returning student back to the university of portsmouth. My 1st application took only 15 working days confused why this is talking to long.

Comment: How ‘returning’? You need to give more background information if you hope to get any meaningful answers. But your question seems to be about longer-term study which is off-topic on TSE, you should ask on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/